# Form to redirect and login to facebook

Tags: html, forms, authentication, facebook

I was wondering if it was possible to create a form on my website that accepts a username and password, and once submitted redirects a user to facebook and logs in automatically?

I am not specifically asking for the code do do such a thing (although that would be appreciated) rather just suggestions of where to start and whether or not it is possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook does not allow xAuth, a feature that would allow for something similar to what you're describing.  Instead, you have to use a standard OAuth flow that involves redirecting the user to Facebook, where they input their credentials, authorize your app, and are then directed back with a token you can use to access to make API calls on their behalf.

FB has a [good guide to their auth here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).  A simple way to get started with this is by using the provided Javascript SDK - [their simplest example](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login), which renders a button the user can use to log in, is:

```
 <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
      <fb:login-button>Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
    </body>
 </html>
```

It's necessary to first [register an app](http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php), which will give you the needed app ID.